Is there still anyway to get audit logs from DefaultConnectingIOReactor in httpclient5?
Abstract
I'm now switching my project denpendency apache-http-component 4 to 5.2 and there are lots of api has changed or removed. And I can't find any useful migration guide for me (even this one https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.3.x/migration-guide/index.html).
My Problem
In 4.x DefaultConnectingIOReactor class has a method getAuditLog() that allows get List<ExceptionEvent> as a result to chekcout when and where occurred this exception, but in 5.x this method has been removed from DefaultConnectingIOReactor and I also can't find what it changed to. Is anyone can help me? Also, where I can find a useful guide for migrating 4 to 5.2?
Is there still anyway to get audit logs from DefaultConnectingIOReactor in httpclient5? And where I can find a useful guide for migrating 4 to 5.2?


Is there still anyway to get audit logs from DefaultConnectingIOReactor in httpclient5?

Use Callback<Exception> exceptionCallback instead.

And where I can find a useful guide for migrating 4 to 5.2?

You are welcome to contribute one.

thx a lot. However I got another question. In the past, I could use HttpRequestBase (now changed to HttpUriRequestBase) as a parameter in CloseableHttpAsyncClient.execute(). However, the execute method now only accepts SimpleHttpRequest and a FutureCallback<SimpleHttpResponse>. Should I change to using SimpleHttpRequest everywhere, or should I just need to convert my HttpUriRequestBase to SimpleHttpRequest?
